# Cannot share volumes between containers in a docker-compose file

Tags: docker, nginx, web, docker-compose, volumes

I want to share the file build that is generated by my react container to my Nginx container.

```
react:
   stdin_open: true
   build:
     dockerfile: ./react.dockerfile
     context: ../frontend
   volumes:
     - /app/node_modules
     - files_built:/app/build
   networks:
     - default
 nginx:
    stdin_open: true
    build:
       dockerfile: ./nginx.dockerfile
       context: ../frontend
    volumes:
       - /app/node_modules
       - ../frontend/nginx:/config
       - files_built:/app/build
    networks:
       - default
    environment:
       - PUID=1000
       - PGID=1000
       - TZ=Europe/London
       - URL=myurl.com
       - VALIDATION=http
       - STAGING=true #optional
    ports:
       - 443:443
       - 80:80 #optional
    depends_on:
       - react
 volumes:
    public:
    db-data:
    files_built:
 networks:
    default:
```

When I go in the react container, the build file is in the folder /app. I am trying to use a named volume (files_build) in both the react and the Nginx containers. But with the code bellow, I cannot find any folder files_built in the VM or build file in the Nginx container (using the command find / -name "build").

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help,
Hugo

Comment: `using the command find / -name "build"` - the path is not a variable `cd /app; ls` should show the folder build - if it doesn't what does it show?

Answer (score 0):

For a typical React application, you'll compile it down to static files and serve those static files; there's no specific need for a running server.  You can use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) for this.  Your Dockerfile would look roughly like:

```bash
FROM node:lts AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm build

FROM nginx
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
# base image contains the right CMD already
```

That means you can remove the `react` container from your Compose setup and reduce the `docker-compose.yml` file to

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    build: ../frontend
    volumes:
       - ../frontend/nginx:/config
    environment:
       - TZ=Europe/London
       - URL=myurl.com
       - VALIDATION=http
       - STAGING=true #optional
    ports:
       - 443:443
       - 80:80 #optional
```

You do not need `volumes:` here.  There are a couple of notable problems with using volumes: since their content never gets updated they are prone to overwriting your application with old content, and they do not translate well to clustered environments like Kubernetes.  It's better to `COPY` content into Docker images than to try to share files between containers.